# Selecting the previous row based on different types in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I have the following table:

[image]

and i want to achieve the following:

[image]

I using Microsoft SQL Server to find the for all withdrawals and then find the first deposit before that withdraw when it was made.

I have tried using `ROW_NUMBER` with `PARTITION BY` however I am not managing because I am getting first deposit from the table and not the first one before that specific withdrawal. Anyone has suggestions?

Comment: *"I have tried using `ROW_NUMBER` with `PARTITION BY`"* Then show us that attempt. [Edit] your question, to include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to do this is using `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT t1.CustomerID
   , t1.TransType
   , t2.[DateTime] AS DepositDate
   , t1.[DateTime] AS WithdrawalDate
FROM t t1
OUTER APPLY 
(
   SELECT TOP 1 [DateTime]
   FROM t t2
   WHERE 
       t1.CustomerID = t2.CustomerID 
       AND 
       t2.[DateTime] < t1.[DateTime] 
       AND 
       TransType = 'Deposit'
   ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC
)
WHERE t1.TransType = 'Withdrawal'
```